# How to safely upgrade GTK+ version?

Tags: debian, gnome, gnome-shell, gtk, gtk3

I'm installing trying to install an extension that requires gtk+ 3.16 but my current version is 3.14 on Debian Jessie 8. The error message that the extension gives me is

`gtkbuilder: required gtk+ version 3.16, current version is 3.14`

I'm looking through synaptic package manager to see if I can find the package but I'm not having any luck. I did some searching and I found this gnome ftp  `https://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/gtk+/3.16/`

I downloaded the package, decompressed it with `sudo tar xf gtk+-3.16.4.tar.xz` then I ran `./configure` it was running for a while until it hit

```
Requested 'glib-2.0 >= 2.43.4' but version of GLib is 2.42.1
    Requested 'atk >= 2.15.1' but version of Atk is 2.14.0

    Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
    installed software in a non-standard prefix.

    Alternatively, you may set the environment variables BASE_DEPENDENCIES_CFLAGS
    and BASE_DEPENDENCIES_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
```

Should I keep installing each dependency one by one until it's done throwing errors at me or is there a way that it can be installed easily without having to install each dependency error. Usually one dependency depends on a bunch of other dependencies and that could be really time consuming. Any tips or suggestions will be highly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
I'm currently doing the install each dependency route I installed `atk 2.15.1` and `glib 2.43.4` and it compiled fine with no errors. But when I try to `./configure` on gtk+-3.16-4 I get the following error.

```
*** 'pkg-config --modversion glib-2.0' returned 2.43.4, but GLIB (2.42.1)
*** was found! If pkg-config was correct, then it is best
*** to remove the old version of GLib. You may also be able to fix the error
*** by modifying your LD_LIBRARY_PATH enviroment variable, or by editing
*** /etc/ld.so.conf. Make sure you have run ldconfig if that is
*** required on your system.
*** If pkg-config was wrong, set the environment variable PKG_CONFIG_PATH
*** to point to the correct configuration files
no
configure: error: 
*** GLIB 2.43.4 or better is required. The latest version of
*** GLIB is always available from ftp://ftp.gtk.org/pub/gtk/.
```

I ran `pkg-config --modversion glib-2.0` and the output was `2.43.4` which means I have the correct glib version installed the error message mentions if this occur to set the environment variable of "PKG_CONFIG_PATH to point to the correct configuration files" but I don't know which file it should point to or what is the path to this file.